# How to create a 'Google Drive' file or folder shortcut, within Google Drive, on Android? (see body of question)

Tags: google-drive

On the web application for desktop this is accomplished by navigating to the file, clicking on it, and pressing Shift + Z.

Is there a way to accomplish the same functionality on Android? Either within the Google Drive app or thru some other means?

NOTE: When I go to a file that's in multiple locations on the Google Drive app and go to: Options -> Details, then I can see all the locations the file is in, and also remove locations, but I can't seem to add locations from this menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Google Drive version 2.20.141.03.34:

1. Select the file(s)
2. Click on the 3-dot menu, then select "Add shortcut to Drive"
3. Select the location where the shortcut(s) should be created.

Answer (score 0):

You can select the file and add to star in google drive, next time when you want to see you can directly click on starred files of folders.

Comment: Hi Mansi, this doesn't answer my question. If you read the question it says "(see body of question)". If you then read the body of the question I feel like it pretty clearly states that I'm trying to accomplish the same functionality as the shift + z shortcut on the google drive web app. Which allows me to create a short cut to a file or folder in any folder. Using the star feature doesn't accomplish that.